# In SQL, how to convert a column of a comma separated key string to a comma separated value string

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting

I have a database table (table A) looks like this, in SQL Server 2016:

TableA:

```
TaskID - TaskName  -  AssignedTo
-------------------------------
1        Task 1       1,4
2        Task 2       3
3        Task 3       2,3
4        Task 4       2,4,5
```

I also have a TableB which is a lookup table for AssignedTo which looks like this:

TableB:

```
AssigneeID - Name
-------------------------------
1            John Smith
2            Janet Wright
3            Tom Morgan
4            Kevin Warren
5            Mike Taylor
```

I want to write a query to be able to genrate the following report/table:

```
TaskID - TaskName  -  NameAssignedTo
------------------------------------------------------------
1        Task 1       John Smith,Kevin Warren
2        Task 2       Tom Morgan
3        Task 3       Janet Wright,Tom Morgan
4        Task 4       Janet Wright,Kevin Warren,Mike Taylor
```

If it can be achieved by writing a SQL query that would be great. Anyone can help? Thank you very much!

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store numbers in strings!  Don't store multiple values in a string!  Declare foreign key relationships!

Comment: Hello @Gordon, thanks for your comment and I just use the two tables above as the example to explain my questions. However the two tables has no formal declared foreign key relationship. Can you help me on the SQL Query? Thank you very much!

Comment: . . Of course they don't.  They **can't**.  That is the purpose of my comment.  Strings and ints are not compatible types.  There *should* be a relationship but you cannot define it.  Learn about junction/association tables and the right way to represent this relationship in SQL.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Hello @Yitzhak Khabinsky, the data sample is TableA and TableB, the actual question is how I can convert comma separated key string (e.g. 1,4) to comma separated value string (e.g. John Smith,Kevin Warren) (TableB is the lookup table, 1 is John Smith and 4 is Kevin Warren). I thought my question is clear but sorry for the confusion. The sql server version I use is SQL Server 2016.

Comment: @Denis I think you asked the question just fine. It was very clear. You dont _need_ to provide a minimal reproducible example, but people are better able to help if you do. Ignore the lectures about how you shouldn't be doing this or that .... sometimes we dont get the choice.

Comment: thank you @codeulike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time you would need to provide ##1-4.
And learn from this answer what it means, i.e. a minimal reproducible example.
You copy it to SSMS and launch it there.

Here is how to implement it in SQL Server 2016:

- `STRING_SPLIT()` to break it down, one **AssignedTo** per row.
- `SELECT ... FOR XML ...` to revert it back to one row for each task.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tblA TABLE (TaskID INT PRIMARY KEY, TaskName VARCHAR(100), AssignedTo VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tblA (TaskID, TaskName, AssignedTo) VALUES
(1, 'Task 1', '1,4'),
(2, 'Task 2', '3'),
(3, 'Task 3', '2,3'),
(4, 'Task 4', '2,4,5');

DECLARE @tblB TABLE (AssigneeID INT PRIMARY KEY, [Name] VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tblB (AssigneeID, [Name]) VALUES
(1, 'John Smith'),
(2, 'Janet Wright'),
(3, 'Tom Morgan'),
(4, 'Kevin Warren'),
(5, 'Mike Taylor')
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT * FROM @tblA
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(AssignedTo, @separator)) AS x
        INNER JOIN @tblB AS b ON x.value = b.AssigneeID
)
SELECT p.TaskID, p.TaskName
    , STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                     CONCAT(@separator, c.Name)
                     FROM cte AS c
                     WHERE c.TaskID = p.TaskID
                     FOR XML PATH ('')),
             1, 1, '') AS NameAssignedTo
FROM cte AS p
GROUP BY p.TaskID, p.TaskName;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| TaskID | TaskName |            NameAssignedTo             |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|      1 | Task 1   | John Smith,Kevin Warren               |
|      2 | Task 2   | Tom Morgan                            |
|      3 | Task 3   | Janet Wright,Tom Morgan               |
|      4 | Task 4   | Janet Wright,Kevin Warren,Mike Taylor |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Charlie, what was the reason to add a `.value(..)` method? There is no XML data type involved.

Comment: Thank you very much @Yitzhak Khabinsky! It seems work and  I will apply it to my real tables to see. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Denis, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Comment: thank you very much and it also works with my live data. I have marked it as the answer!. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The schema you have is fundamentally **broken**. You *really* want an additional table here to express the `TaskAssignments` like this:

| TaskID | Assignee |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |

You can find other solutions that will give you the results for this query, but this will make it *much* easier to write, it will perform multiple orders of magnitude better, and it's also better for answering questions (queries) you haven't even thought to ask yet.

General rule of thumb here: **humans** prefer fewer, wider tables, but **computers** do better with more, narrower tables. So we design the database storage to appease the computer, and write reports to show combined data for the humans.

Comment: thank you @Joel for the comment! I understand it is better to have the additional table in the middle to identify the multiple to multiple relationship. However at this time, my task is to write a report, not to fundamentally to change the code and the database structure.